# Companies / Products using WiX toolset

Tags: deployment, wix, setup-deployment, wix3.11

I don't know whether my question match with my title or not.

I'm currently doing a POC on developing msi and exe files for installation using WiX toolset.
I need to give a report on that.So we need to know,

1. Which all are companies or products are using WiX toolset for the development of setup.
2. About the license of WiX. I have read license, but didn't understand about it.
3. Can we use WiX for production.

Anyone knowing about this please help me.

Comment: Heading out the door, got these quick links for you: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225031/windows-service-not-shown-in-add-remove-programs-under-control-panel/50229840#50229840) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864). Many companies have used WiX - maybe corporate teams in particular - certainly for in-house software.

Comment: If you [search github.com for WiX source files](https://github.com/search?q=*.wxs+extension%3Awxs&type=Code) you get thousands of hits.

Comment: I have an open source project that accelerates learning and authoring of WiX.  I'd be sure to include it in your POC.  You can learn about it here: http://www.github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. A number of your questions, including this one, look like very poor fits for this site

Answer (score 0):

- Which all are companies or products are using WiX toolset for the development of setup. *Microsoft used it for shipping Visual Studio, not sure if they still use it. I think they do*
- - About the license of WiX. I have read license, but didn't understand about it. *what part do you have questions about?*
- Can we use WiX for production. *YES - people use it all the time.*

Comment: Please briefly explain about the license.